# how to replace middle number between a stirng with out any change in left and right

Tags: sql

I have a column in which have have numbers in a unique pattern like 
30201600601
Now i want to change 2016 to 2014 without effecting 30 and 00601 In Sql Server 2012 please can any help me.

Comment: If the string is **`30201602016`**, then how?

Comment: which db? mysql or postgres?

Comment: I Don't Know to replace the middle number by query if there is any way guide me

Comment: Mutaqeem Bhai it is SQl

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE number 
  ( 
     id VARCHAR(200) 
  ); 

INSERT INTO number 
VALUES      (30201600601); 

SELECT Replace(id, Substring(id, 3, 6), 2014) 
FROM   number;
```

Regards,

Saravanan

Comment: Dear Savaranan, Table name is Bale Coulumn name is baleid string is 30201600601 and want to replace 2016 to 2014 what next

Answer (score 0):

```
update table_name set col_name = SUBSTRING(col_name, 1, 2) + '2014' + SUBSTRING(col_name, 7, 5).
```

For more information, you can check [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql).

Another method could be using `replace` function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql

Comment: Thanks Mustaqeem Bhai Great